# AngularJS and jQuery together

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In the project i'm making i want to use some jQuery with Angular 1.4... in the login of the app, i have this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var animating = false,
      submitPhase1 = 1100,
      submitPhase2 = 400,
      logoutPhase1 = 800,
      $login = $(".login"),
      $app = $(".app");
  
  function ripple(elem, e) {
    $(".ripple").remove();
    var elTop = elem.offset().top,
        elLeft = elem.offset().left,
        x = e.pageX - elLeft,
        y = e.pageY - elTop;
    var $ripple = $("<div class='ripple'></div>");
    $ripple.css({top: y, left: x});
    elem.append($ripple);
  };
  
  $(document).on("click", ".login__submit", function(e) {
    if (animating) return;
    animating = true;
    var that = this;
    ripple($(that), e);
    $(that).addClass("processing");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(that).addClass("success");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $app.show();
        $app.css("top");
        $app.addClass("active");
      }, submitPhase2 - 70);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $login.hide();
        $login.addClass("inactive");
        animating = false;
        $(that).removeClass("success processing");
      }, submitPhase2);
    }, submitPhase1);
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".app__logout", function(e) {
    if (animating) return;
    $(".ripple").remove();
    animating = true;
    var that = this;
    $(that).addClass("clicked");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $app.removeClass("active");
      $login.show();
      $login.css("top");
      $login.removeClass("inactive");
    }, logoutPhase1 - 120);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $app.hide();
      animating = false;
      $(that).removeClass("clicked");
    }, logoutPhase1);
  });
  
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  html, body {
    font-size: 40%;
  }
}

svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  overflow: visible;
}

.svg-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.svg-icon path {
  stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

input, button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/UP7fWfg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.demo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  margin-top: -26.5rem;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 53rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.login {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(146, 135, 187, 0.8) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(146, 135, 187, 0.8) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 100%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.17, -0.65, 0.665, 1.25);
          transition: opacity 0.1s, transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.17, -0.65, 0.665, 1.25);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}
.login.inactive {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1);
}
.login__check {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16rem;
  left: 13.5rem;
  width: 14rem;
  height: 2.8rem;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
          transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.login__check:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 2.8rem;
  height: 5.2rem;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset -0.2rem -2rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.login__form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.login__row {
  height: 5rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.login__icon {
  margin-bottom: -0.4rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
.login__icon.name path {
  stroke-dasharray: 73.50196075439453;
  stroke-dashoffset: 73.50196075439453;
  -webkit-animation: animatePath 2s 0.5s forwards;
          animation: animatePath 2s 0.5s forwards;
}
.login__icon.pass path {
  stroke-dasharray: 92.10662841796875;
  stroke-dashoffset: 92.10662841796875;
  -webkit-animation: animatePath 2s 0.5s forwards;
          animation: animatePath 2s 0.5s forwards;
}
.login__input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22rem;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background: transparent;
  color: #FDFCFD;
}
.login__submit {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  margin: 5rem 0 2.2rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  background: #FF3366;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s 0.15s, font-size 0.1s 0.15s;
          transition: width 0.3s 0.15s, font-size 0.1s 0.15s;
}
.login__submit:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.5rem;
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 2px dotted #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 0.5s infinite linear;
          animation: rotate 0.5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s 0.4s;
          transition: opacity 0.1s 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.login__submit.processing {
  width: 4rem;
  font-size: 0;
}
.login__submit.processing:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.login__submit.success {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.1s 0.3s, background-color 0.1s 0.3s;
          transition: transform 0.3s 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.1s 0.3s, background-color 0.1s 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(30);
      -ms-transform: scale(30);
          transform: scale(30);
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.login__submit.success:after {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s 0s;
          transition: opacity 0.1s 0s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.login__signup {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #ABA8AE;
}
.login__signup a {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.app {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.45, 0.465, 1.25);
          transition: opacity 0.1s, transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.45, 0.465, 1.25);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2);
}
.app.active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}
.app.active .app__user-photo {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}
.app.active .app__meeting {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0);
          transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.app.active .app__logout {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}
.app__top {
  position: relative;
  height: 28rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 6rem 1.5rem 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.app__bot {
  position: relative;
  height: 25rem;
  background: #fff;
}
.app__menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.8rem;
  height: 1.7rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.app__menu-btn span, .app__menu-btn:before, .app__menu-btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.app__menu-btn span {
  top: 0.8rem;
}
.app__menu-btn:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
}
.app__menu-btn:after {
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
}
.app__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
}
.app__icon.search {
  right: 1.5rem;
  stroke-dasharray: 61.847137451171875;
  stroke-dashoffset: 61.847137451171875;
  -webkit-animation: animatePath 0.5s 0.5s forwards;
          animation: animatePath 0.5s 0.5s forwards;
}
.app__hello {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.app__user {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9rem;
  height: 9rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.app__user-photo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.35, 0.56, 1.55);
          transition: transform 0.3s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.35, 0.56, 1.55);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      -ms-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
}
.app__user-notif {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #50D2C2;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.app__month:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.app__month-name {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.app__month-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.app__month-btn.left {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
          transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.app__month-btn.right {
  float: right;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.app__days {
  height: 7rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.app__day {
  width: 14%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.app__day.weekday {
  color: #919197;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.app__day.date {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3C3C43;
}
.app__meeting {
  position: relative;
  height: 6rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEF;
  padding: 1rem 2rem 1rem 7.5rem;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
          transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
}
.app__meeting:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.app__meeting:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.app__meeting:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
          transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.app__meeting:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
          transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.app__meeting:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.6s;
          transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
.app__meeting-photo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2rem;
  top: 1rem;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
.app__meeting-name {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
.app__meeting-info {
  color: #949498;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.app__logout {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3.3rem;
  right: 3.3rem;
  width: 4.6rem;
  height: 4.6rem;
  margin-right: -2.3rem;
  margin-bottom: -2.3rem;
  background: #FC3768;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 0.4s 0.1s, right 0.4s 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.4s 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.7s, background-color 0.1s 0.7s;
          transition: bottom 0.4s 0.1s, right 0.4s 0.1s, transform 0.4s 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.7s, background-color 0.1s 0.7s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      -ms-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
}
.app__logout.clicked {
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(30) !important;
      -ms-transform: scale(30) !important;
          transform: scale(30) !important;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.app__logout.clicked svg {
  opacity: 0;
}
.app__logout-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.5rem;
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s;
          transition: opacity 0.1s;
}
.app__logout-icon path {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-dasharray: 64.36235046386719;
  stroke-dashoffset: 64.36235046386719;
  -webkit-animation: animatePath 0.5s 0.5s forwards;
          animation: animatePath 0.5s 0.5s forwards;
}

.ripple {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  margin-left: -7.5rem;
  margin-top: -7.5rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      -ms-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-animation: animRipple 0.4s;
          animation: animRipple 0.4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animRipple {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3.5);
            transform: scale(3.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animRipple {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3.5);
            transform: scale(3.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatePath {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes animatePath {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="demo">
    <div class="login">
      <div class="login__check"></div>
      <div class="login__form">
        <div class="login__row">
          <svg class="login__icon name svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <path d="M0,20 a10,8 0 0,1 20,0z M10,0 a4,4 0 0,1 0,8 a4,4 0 0,1 0,-8" />
          </svg>
          <input type="text" class="login__input name" placeholder="Username"/>
        </div>
        <div class="login__row">
          <svg class="login__icon pass svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <path d="M0,20 20,20 20,8 0,8z M10,13 10,16z M4,8 a6,8 0 0,1 12,0" />
          </svg>
          <input type="password" class="login__input pass" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="login__submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="login__signup">Don't have an account? &nbsp;<a>Sign up</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="app">
      <div class="app__top">
        <div class="app__menu-btn">
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <svg class="app__icon search svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
          <!-- yeap, its purely hardcoded numbers straight from the head :D (same for svg above) -->
          <path d="M20,20 15.36,15.36 a9,9 0 0,1 -12.72,-12.72 a 9,9 0 0,1 12.72,12.72" />
        </svg>
        <p class="app__hello">Good Morning!</p>
        <div class="app__user">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/joyWJEY.jpg" alt="" class="app__user-photo" />
          <span class="app__user-notif">3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="app__month">
          <span class="app__month-btn left"></span>
          <p class="app__month-name">March</p>
          <span class="app__month-btn right"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="app__bot">
        <div class="app__days">
          <div class="app__day weekday">Sun</div>
          <div class="app__day weekday">Mon</div>
          <div class="app__day weekday">Tue</div>
          <div class="app__day weekday">Wed</div>
          <div class="app__day weekday">Thu</div>
          <div class="app__day weekday">Fri</div>
          <div class="app__day weekday">Sad</div>
          <div class="app__day date">8</div>
          <div class="app__day date">9</div>
          <div class="app__day date">10</div>
          <div class="app__day date">11</div>
          <div class="app__day date">12</div>
          <div class="app__day date">13</div>
          <div class="app__day date">14</div>
        </div>
        <div class="app__meetings">
          <div class="app__meeting">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/joyWJEY.jpg" alt="" class="app__meeting-photo" />
            <p class="app__meeting-name">Feed the cat</p>
            <p class="app__meeting-info">
              <span class="app__meeting-time">8 - 10am</span>
              <span class="app__meeting-place">Real-life</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="app__meeting">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/joyWJEY.jpg" alt="" class="app__meeting-photo" />
            <p class="app__meeting-name">Feed the cat!</p>
            <p class="app__meeting-info">
              <span class="app__meeting-time">1 - 3pm</span>
              <span class="app__meeting-place">Real-life</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="app__meeting">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/joyWJEY.jpg" alt="" class="app__meeting-photo" />
            <p class="app__meeting-name">FEED THIS CAT ALREADY!!!</p>
            <p class="app__meeting-info">
              <span class="app__meeting-time">This button is just for demo ></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="app__logout">
        <svg class="app__logout-icon svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
          <path d="M6,3 a8,8 0 1,0 8,0 M10,0 10,12"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've already setup the angular app, already created the routes(ui-route), but when opening the login route i see nothing, no console errors, a blank page...

I load jQuery library and the jquery script before angular.

What do i have to do to get the same result using Angular?, in Angular docs says:

> Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.

So what's wrong!? what's needed to make this snippet work in my Angular app?, do i have to take the jquery code to a controller? if so, how?

Comment: It appears that this HTML may be a template page? You mention that JQuery is loaded before angular, but you have a script tag for JQuery as the first line on this HTML template, which isn't going to work correctly.

Comment: `document.ready` is pretty much worthless in angular app with routing with exception of the very little html that might exist in index. Put that code into directives so elements exist when it runs.

Comment: Also note that trying to overlay angular on top of jQuery pages is completely backwards approach also and will present significant problems rather than getting angular running and sprinking jQuery into it as needed. Most of what you have in your jQuery will not be needed if use angular properly

Comment: @Claies No no, that line is added by the Snippet when you select the jQuery Library

Comment: @charlietfl Didn't thought about it, how would i make a directive of it?

Comment: @JonthanSolorzano personally I would rewrite the whole thing in angular. Will be far less code

Comment: Mmmm, could you make an example of doing that @charlietfl?

Comment: how about you make the initial demo setup with enough css to make it work ... your asking quite a bit to get a rewrite done for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83639/discussion-between-jonthan-solorzano-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be completely rewritten into directives in order for jQuery to be used properly for DOM manipulation (which it looks like thats all your template does is some basic DOM manipulation). http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2752-using-jquery-instead-of-jqlite-in-angularjs.htm is a great resource on how to use jQuery the right way in your Angular modules (if you want to still do it this way).

Your code is not modular in the way that AngularJS is, to accomplish this same thing in angular it looks entirely different. You would have tasks like:

```
function ripple(elem, e) {
    $(".ripple").remove();
    var elTop = elem.offset().top,
        elLeft = elem.offset().left,
        x = e.pageX - elLeft,
        y = e.pageY - elTop;
    var $ripple = $("<div class='ripple'></div>");
    $ripple.css({top: y, left: x});
    elem.append($ripple);
  };
```

Would instead look like:

** May not actually work untested, but this is an approach **

```
app.directive('ripple', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(elm){

    function ripple(elm, e) {
      var event = e;
      var elem = $(elm);
      $(".ripple").remove();
      var elTop = elem.offset().top,
        elLeft = elem.offset().left,
        x = e.pageX - elLeft,
        y = e.pageY - elTop;
      var $ripple = $("<div class='ripple'></div>");
      $ripple.css({top: y, left: x});
      elem.append($ripple);

    }
     elm.onclick = function(event){
         ripple(elm, event);
     };
    },

  };
});
```

Call into action after first loading jQuery, then Angular:

`<button data-ripple>Click Me!</button>`

Comment: Mmm, i haven't worked with jQuery that much to rewrite it's code into a directive, i know that the blog you addressed makes an example, but could you explain it rewriting something from the snippet?

Comment: Although the code above MAY work... you really shouldn't be doing this in this way, instead your entire module would be actually structured different. You would be using $timeout instead of the window.timeout function that your using etc.

Comment: You cannot expect anyone to rewrite all of that code for you, thats not what this is about. The explanation I have above should be comprehensive enough to understand. If you do not know jQuery and you do not know AngularJS, then this is not going to be very straight forward for you.

Comment: I know some of AngularJS, but not too much of jQuery, just some basics, i'll try to do what you said and see if it works, if not ill update the post with an edit of the code tried

Comment: Well you know then, in Angular the dom is modified automatically by changing a $scope. What you are doing here is modifying the DOM directly  outside of Angulars "knowledge". This is what you will read over and over and over again not to do. The beauty of AngularJS is you do not have to worry about manipulating the DOM like jquery

Comment: I know you dont know jQuery very well but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background this post should really help you see the path you are on. Dont forget to click the checkmark if you accept this for your answer.